# Finding column combination that forms distinct entry in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I have a very bizarre situation where I have a tons of tables in a database and I need to find which column combination make entries distinct.

There is no documentation, and for reasons, we can't use the "official" primary key which is an SID.

The "non-official" primary key can be a combination of 1 to 300 columns.

Do you guys have any idea on how I can output the right column list for each table in the database?

I feel like doing select distinct for each columns combination is a bit overkill, since some table have 300 columns!

Any tips or insight would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Hunt down the developer of the database, that's a start.

Comment: The database is pretty old and the new DBA have no clues on how to solve this except finding columns combinations by hands. I dont want do go on each table trying to figure out which field does what so I am looking for a way to automatise it ...

Comment: "The non-official primary key can be a combination of 1 to 300 columns" ... that's a lot of permutations to wade through! Presumably there are no unique constraints in place already? If the developer is unavailable, then what about the business analyst? If you don't know which columns need to be unique then you/someone are going to have to go back to first priniciples and talk to the owners of the data (ie "the business") and then work out how that translates into your tables and their unique constraints.